# Push messages in avro format via golang to kafka

Tags: go, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry

I was trying to push a few messages to kafka via confluent go client, but the catch is that messages need to be pushed in avro format. The same can easily achieved in java springboot application.

I have a hunch as in if at all this is possible via confluent go client. Though i have an alternative to push these messages via confluent rest proxy but that would mean 3-4x performance hit, which i would resist from doing.

I tried goAvro to convert the messages in avro. Although i don't get any error while producing but the data part is not being stored in avro format.
[image]

```
avroCodec, err := goavro.NewCodec(schemaString)

if err != nil {
    log.Panic(err.Error())
}

appointmentByte,_ := json.Marshal(appointment)

native, _, _ := avroCodec.NativeFromTextual(appointmentByte)

binaryValue, _ := avroCodec.BinaryFromNative(nil,  native)

var recordValue []byte

schemaIDBytes := make([]byte, 4)
binary.BigEndian.PutUint32(schemaIDBytes, uint32(id))

recordValue = append(recordValue, byte(0))
recordValue = append(recordValue, schemaIDBytes...)
recordValue = append(recordValue, binaryValue...)

log.Print(recordValue)

key, _ := uuid.NewUUID()

fmt.Print(key.String())
p.Produce(&kafka.Message{
    TopicPartition: kafka.TopicPartition{
        Topic: &topic, Partition: kafka.PartitionAny},
    Key: []byte(key.String()), Value: recordValue}, nil)
```

Comment: Can you try to make a minimal, individual piece of code and show us.

Comment: @nilsocket the code above handles encoding part of the message

Comment: {
    "topic": "appointment-value",
    "key": "4efcfb26-42cd-11ea-a7f5-3af9d398b113",
    "value": "\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000+",
    "partition": 0,
    "offset": 4
  }

Comment: The raw version of data stored at kafka is in the above manner

Comment: `json.Marshal(appointment)` creates json, not Avro... Where are you getting the ID from?

Comment: @cricket_007 i got the id from a schema registry, the only issue i am having is a way to convert my go struct to avro binary which is expected.

Comment: Seen this? https://github.com/lensesio/schema-registry

Comment: @cricket_007  i had already configured schema registry. The only issue i was facing was with avro binary encoding .  "github.com/hamba/avro" helped me to do this.

Comment: @cricket_007 the code works like a charm when replacing goavro and json.marshal

Comment: Then you're not using Avro at that point?

Comment: @cricket_007 I am using avro .The issue is solved now i am able to push avro encoded data to kafka. Thanks and cheers.

Comment: Feel free to post your solution as an answer

Comment: @RahulSingh can you please share the solution I am also stuck with same problem

Answer (score 0):

You could search Github for solutions to your issue. It's currently not part of the project, but it's being worked on

https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/issues/69